# How can I search array index of xml data for a matching string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays

Hi I have an array of xml data.  Each array index contains a product element; the product element has child elements such as name, price etc.  I output the contents of the array to a table where it is displayed and this works fine.  I now want to be able to display certain manufacturers on the click of a checkbox(remove them when clicked) so what I am trying to do is access my global results array, loop through each index and within each index find the 'make' element and check if that contains the matching text.  If it does match remove that index entirely from the array and out put the remaining array.  I'm looping through the array using an each function but I can't seem to find a match.  Does anyone have any advice thanks?

Below is my checkbox code.  Once checkbox is checked loop through the array results and find 
make text node.
if the text matches the target word alert but it doesnt find it.

```
 if ($("#activision").is(':checked')){
    $.each(results, function() {
    var check = $(this).find('make').text();
    var word="activision";
    if(check==word){

    alert('found');
    }
```

And a brief look at creating my results array.
For each product element in xml push onto array.

```
results.push({
        productname: $(this).find('productname').text(),
        verdict: $(this).find('verdict').text(),
        description: $(this).find('description').text(),
        price: $(this).find('price').text(),
        make: $(this).find('make').text(),
        date:yyyymmdd,
        rating:$(this).find("rating").text(),
        image:imageurl,
        page:sitepage,
    });
```

Comment: The last thing I tried was using regex but inspect element on chrome says object Object has no method match.  $.each(results, function(i,l) {
  if($(i).match(/activision/g)){
  alert('found');
  }

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved it was a mix up with syntax like I thought it was.  The solution is simply

$.each(results, function() {

if(this.make=="activision"){

alert('found');
  }